# how to send long complex array with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, socket.io

I have complex an array containing lots of base64 data. and I send this array to server with socket.io.
If I send an array containing one or two base64 data. the function is working successfully. but if I send an array containing lots of base64 data. function does not react.

**my purpose**

- client will prepare templates.
- When the client clicks the save button, it sends this template to the server with socket.io.
- templates sent to the server will be saved to hdd with nodejs.

**my array template**

```
const MyArray = [
{
div_id:div.id,
div_innerhtml:div.innerHTML,  //<img src=base64...
div_backgroundimage : div.backgroundimage //base64... 
}
]
```

**client-side code**

```
const MyArray=[],SaveBtn = document.queryselector("#save_div");
    
const SendArray = (ARRAY)=>{
    socket.emit("div_data",ARRAY);
}

SaveBtn.onclick = ()=>{
    SendArray(MyArray);
}
```

**server-side code**

```
socket.on("div_data",(data)=>{
    console.log(data)   // function does not react.
    let JSON_DATA = JSON.stringify(data)
    console.log(JSON_DATA)   // function does not react.
});
```

Is this socket.io error?
What should I do or how should I research this issue?

**UPDATE**

network tab in devtools

for two base64 image : (function work successfully)

[image]

for four base64 image : (function does not react)

[image]

Comment: What does the network tab say in devtools?

Comment: This doesn't strike me as an appropriate use case for sockets. Why not HTTP? How long and how complex is this array?

Comment: Wiktor , I added the devtools results to my question

Comment: ggorlen, because this project must work in the browser and the electron project. Actually, the server and client will be on the same computer. I know there is no way to save files from the browser with javascript. That's why I chose socket.io. and i can't use ipcrenderer.